# Naming directories in python?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, error

Why is it that when I label my directories this way:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\\Users\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
scratch = "C:\\Users\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
space = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS" #General Directory
workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Textfiles" #Where the final product is saved
folder = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\AQS\\site_coordinates\\" #Location of the the site data
textfile_place = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Textfiles\\pollution.txt" #Final Textfile
data = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Textfiles\\data.txt" #Location of data
```

it reads all of my data, but when I try to clean it up and make it more transferable across computers like this:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
space = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS"
scratch = space + "\\Testing"
workspace = space + "\\Textfiles"
textfile_place = workspace + "\\pollution.txt"
data = workspace + "data.txt"
folder = space + "\\AQS\\site_coordinates\\"
```

it doesn't work and says the files don't exist? I've been trying to look on the web but can't find a solution to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `os` Python module will help you solve this problem.  For example:

```
import os, arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Testing"
space = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\ArcGIS"

scratch = os.path.join(space, "Testing")
workspace = os.path.join(space, "Textfiles")
textfile_place = os.path.join(workspace, "pollution.txt")
data = os.path.join(workspace, "data.txt")
folder = os.path.join(space, "AQS", "site_coordinates")
```

Comment: Nice answer Aaron, simple and concise. Alex, something else that may help is os.path.exists(path) to check for an object in your filesystem, this will return true if a file or folder matches path - couple with os.path.isdir(path) to confirm if a folder exists and then use os.mkdirs(path) to create the folder if you can't find it.